# Why concating two videos with ffmpeg (5s and 33s) produce 4m34s video in slow motion

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion, concatenation

I am developing a service to concat a video (mine) with a another from a user (he/she upload it) and return to user.

First I tried to use [Concat demuxer](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate) because I don't want to re-encode videos if it is not needed. It is supposed that with same codec it should concat videos almost immediately.

Users may upload different videos with different codecs so I will need to convert that video to a certain codec. The problem that I have now is that even having videos with same codec concat is not working well, so I would like to know what else is needed.

My mylist.txt

```
file './myVideo1.mp4'
file './userVideo1.mp4'
```

Command:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -c copy mergedVideo.mp4
```

It didn't work because [there were different audio codecs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9Vla.png) (pcm_u8 vs aac) so I converted `myVideo1` audio to aac with;

```
ffmpeg -i myVideo1.mp4 -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -acodec libfaac -vcodec copy myVideo1_aac.mp4
```

This was an intermediate task, I mention it because [I had a warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwyrC.png):

> Codec for stream 0 does not use global headers but container format
>   requires global headers

At this point I have two videos with same audio and codec, lets see details:
[image: myVideo1_aac.mp4]
[image: userVideo1.mp4 info]

I tried to concat videos as before...

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -c copy mergedVideo.mp4
```

... and [there were no errors shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCdya.png), but when I played the video I saw first video normal however 2nd was super slow, only few frames per second, in fact mergedVideo.mp4 has 4 minutes and 34 seconds when it should have 39s (5.38 + 33.79).

Here is mergedVideo.mp4 info:
[image]

Can you tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Your videos run at different framerates (25 and 27.54) and have different tbr/tbn/tbc. I'd suggest you reencode your second video to match those of the first one.

Comment: Do you know the command to do it? I Changed the frame rate but I still need to change tbr/tbn/tbc. Thanks